# Adding numbers until a negative is encountered

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that lets the user enter numbers(maximum entries>10^6) until a negative is encountered. I've tried a lot of version but they either don't register that a negative value is entered or they crash.

This is where I'm currently at:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HIGHEST 999999
int main(){
    int i=0, entry, sum=0;
        while(i<HIGHEST){
            scanf("%i", entry);
            if(entry>0){
                sum+=entry;
            }
            else{
            i=HIGHEST;  
            }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Sum: %i", sum);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
scanf("%i", entry);
```

Which should be:

```
scanf("%i", &entry);
```

You need to pass in the address of the integer variable that will store the scanned value.  Since
entry was never initialized, it is just filled with garbage/whatever is in memory and not the entered value.  See this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), which states,

```
  "Depending on the format string, the function may expect a sequence of additional arguments,     
  each containing a pointer to allocated storage where the interpretation of the extracted 
  characters is stored with the appropriate type"
```

Comment: In fact, it is a good exercise to run this program by printing out the value of entry before it is used.  That way you can see the crazy stuff that gets shoved in that uninitialized zone.

Comment: Thanks a ton, shouldn't have missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

You provide a way to leave if the entered number is too big:

```
while(i<HIGHEST){
```

But nothing to leave if it is less than 0;  Try this:

```
while((i<HIGHEST)&&(i>=0)){
```

Additionally, @OldProgrammer is correct, your `scanf()` should be as he has pointed out.

Comment: Do I need to do that even if there's nothing that would make i<0?

Comment: @user2962716 -   In your problem description:  _until a negative is encountered._, you imply that the program should run until a negative is encountered, (and smaller than a 1000000)  That is why I offered that suggestion :)